# How to Evaluate $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}H_{4n-3} $

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, harmonic-numbers

I came across the following result:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}H_{4n-3} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{5\pi^2}{32}+\frac{\ln^2(2)}{8}-\frac{3\ln(2)}{2}+\frac{\ln^2(1+\sqrt{2})}{2}+\frac{\ln(3-2\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$H_{4n-3}$ refers to Harmonic Numbers

However Mathematica is not able to compute it as it gives an enormous result full of `PolyLog`s and `Root`s of functions.

Could someone please provide a proof for the above result?

Comment: Since you can't or won't explain why you care, why would anybody else? Have you even checked if it's true or likely (numerically)? Have you done *any* research except asking Mathematica and MSE?

Comment: @ProfessorVector  I have checked numerically , as well as have a proof. However the proof is quite messy , and i would consider it to NOT be elegant at all. Thus i wanted to see if there exist simpler proofs than mine which takes up several pages. If i can learn from proofs how to see things from a different perspective i can surely save up a lot of time. Cheers.

Comment: How would anybody know if their proof is simpler than yours?! Your attitude of saving *your* time at the expense of others will make you rather popular, hereabouts.

Comment: @ProfessorVector im NOT asking anybody to tell whether their proof is simpler or more complex than mine?? Im simply asking if the value of an infinite series can be proven , same way many others have done on this site , your negative attitude is surely helping others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite series is
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}H_{4n+1} = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{x^{4n+1}-1}{x-1}\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3\log(2)-\log(1+x^4)}{x^3(1-x)}\,dx$$
and Mathematica is able to deal with the integral, even if the simplification of dilogarithms has to be carried out by hand. By using integration by parts the RHS boils down to elementary integrals and
$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}\log(x)\,dx,\qquad I_2=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}\log(1-x)\,dx. $$
Of course
$$ I_1 = \sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1} (-1)^n x^{4n+3}\log(x)\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+4)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{192}$$
so the whole problem is more or less equivalent to the computation of $I_2$, which can be performed by enforcing the substitution $x=1-z$, computing a partial fraction decomposition and exploiting
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)}{x-a}\,dx =\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{a}\right).$$
This is strongly reminiscent of the trick I used at page $3$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04269.pdf).